# Precise Shot and Improved precise shot

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, ranger, ranged-attack

If I have the [Improved Precise Shot](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-precise-shot-combat-final/) feat through the Ranger's [Archery Combat Style](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/ranger/ranger-combat-styles/), but don't have [Precise Shot](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/precise-shot-combat-final/), do I still incur the -4 penalty to ranged attacks for firing into melee?

Comment: You actually quoted all of the relevant rules in your post...which part of that gave rise to doubt??

Answer (score 6):

**Yes.**

The benefit of Improved Precise Shot is:

> Your ranged attacks ignore the **AC bonus** granted to targets by anything less than total **cover**, and the miss chance granted to targets by anything less than total **concealment**. Total cover and total concealment provide their normal benefits against your ranged attacks.

The benefit of Precise Shot is:

> You can shoot or throw ranged weapons at an opponent engaged in melee without taking the **standard –4 penalty** on your attack roll.

The penalty for firing into melee is not an **AC bonus**, and is not specified as being due to **cover** or **concealment**, so IPS doesn't cover it.

(Also, on a meta level, if you automatically got the effects of PS from taking IPS, why would *any* ranger *ever* take PS?)